Does there exist a unique minimal DFA with more than one start state?
Given a regular language $L\subseteq\Sigma^*$, there exists a unique minimal DFA with minimal number of states that accepts $L$.
On the other hand, it is well-known that there does not exist a unique minimal NFA with the same property.
I would like to know about an intermediate question: is there a unique minimal "pseudo-DFA", in which more than one initial state is allowed, realizing $L$?
Even better, is there a fast ($n\log n$) algorithm finding it?
In some examples I'm looking at (coming from dynamics), I suspect that there exist much nicer pseudo-DFA than classical DFA; essentially the DFA I get consist of a tree rooted at the start state that "feeds into" a pseudo-DFA.
As a silly example, $a^*+b^*$ is given by a $2$-state pseudo-DFA with loops $a,b$ respectively at both start states; while its minimal DFA has $3$ states.
If this helps, all states are final in my automata.

Even a small extension of the deterministic model towards a nondeterministic one results in the complexity of minimization to jump from $\text{P}$ to $\text{NP-complete}$. For example, allowing two initial states instead of one results in an intractable minimization problem.
The result is shown in this paper by Andreas Malcher.

Consider the language $L = a\mid \Sigma^*b$. If I am not mistaken, the minimal DFA has the following transition table:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
& a & b\\
\hline
\rightarrow q_0 & q_1 & q_1\\
\hline
q_1\rightarrow & q_2 & q_1\\
\hline
q_2 & q_2 & q_1\\
\hline
\end{array}$$
However, if you add $q_2$ as a second starting state, the recognized language does not change.

Thanks a lot!
You're right that in this case there are two minimal-sized automata, so uniqueness fails; but I'd also like to accept the other answer which gives a very useful link, and SE won't allow me to split the votes. Is it OK if I "only" upvote you?

That's alright, it up to you to accept the answer that was most useful!
